# how to pause and stop a changing ImageView

Tags: android

i have an ImageView in which the picture switches every 5s, i am trying to add a pause and

resume button that can stop and restart the action.  i am using a Handler, Runnable, and

postDelay() for image switch, and i put the code on onResume.  i am thinking about using

wait and notify for the pause and resume, but that would mean creating an extra thread.  so

far for the thread, i have this:

class RecipeDisplayThread extends Thread 
    {
        boolean pleaseWait = false;

```
    // This method is called when the thread runs
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // Do work

            // Check if should wait
            synchronized (this) {
                while (pleaseWait) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            // Do work
        }
    }

}
```

and in the main activity's onCreate():

```
        Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                while (true) {

                synchronized (thread) 
                {
                    thread.pleaseWait = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        Button resumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume);

        resumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                while (true) {

                // Resume the thread
                synchronized (thread) 
                {
                    thread.pleaseWait = false;
                    thread.notify();
                }
                }

            }
        });
```

the pause button seems to work, but then after that i can't press any other button, such as

the resume button.

thanks.

Comment: Please choose more useful tags than "pause" and "resume".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am using a Handler, Runnable, and
>   postDelay() for image switch

Why? Why not use `postDelayed()` and get rid of the `Thread` and `Handler`?

```
  void doTheImageUpdate() {
    if (areWeStillRunning) {
      myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever);
      myImageView.postDelayed(updater, 5000);
    }
  }

  Runnable updater=new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      doTheImageUpdate();
    }
  };
```

When you want to start updating, set `areWeStillRunning` to `true` and call `doTheImageUpdate()`. When you want to stop updating, set `areWeStillRunning` to `false`. You'll need to work out the edge case of where the user presses pause and resume within 5 seconds, to prevent doubling things up, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

If you really want to use a background thread, you will want to learn more about how to use background threads. For example, `while(true) {}` without any form of exit will never work. There are some good books on the subject, such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

Comment: it works now, i just needed to work out the edge cases.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to answer my own question, but the comment section is too small.

i did this (per CommonsWare):

```
private Runnable mWaitRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() 
    {
        doTheImageUpdate();
    }
};

private void doTheImageUpdate()
{
    try
    {
        if(bStillRunning)
        {

            sText = "Step one: unpack egg";
            iDrawable = R.drawable.monster2;

            t.setText(sText);
            mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), iDrawable);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(mImage);

            tts1 = new TTS(getApplicationContext(), ttsInitListener, true);             

            mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 5000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("mWaitRunnable.run()", e.getMessage());
    }

}



        Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {

                bStillRunning = false;

            }
        });

        Button resumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume);

        resumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {

                bStillRunning = true;

            }
        });
```

again pause works but resume doesn't.  and i have already simplified my problem by making the text, the image, and delay time the same for all the steps.  i was hoping to make these variable, in additional to the number of steps.